# ActiveX Text Boxes in Excel Flash Old Value When Losing Focus

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet that contains a number of ActiveX text boxes.

When data is entered into a text box, and the text box loses focus, it briefly flashes its old value before displaying the new value. This happens for all text boxes in any workbook I create, whether they have code associated with them or not.

This feels like it's a new thing to start happening to me over the past few weeks, and I can't for the life of me work out how to make it stop.

Does anyone have any suggestions?